# Difference between "depend on abstractions not concrete classes" and "program to an interface"

Tags: oop, design-principles

The difference between these two principles is not clear for me. They just look like the same thing.

What is the difference if any?

Answer (score 7):

From the book Head First Design Patterns, page 139, concerning the "Dependency Inversion" principle:

> Dependency Inversion principle: Depend upon abstractions. Do not depend upon concrete classes.
>
> At first, this principle sounds a lot like "program to an interface, not an implementation", right? It is similar; however, the Dependency Inversion Principle makes an even stronger statement about abstraction. It suggests that our high-level components should not depend on our low-level components; rather, they should *both* depend on abstractions.
>
> A "high-level" component is a class with behaviour defined in terms of other "low level" components. For example, `PizzaStore` is a high-level component because its behaviour is defined in terms of pizzas - it creates all the different pizza objects, prepares, bakes, cuts, and boxes them, while the pizzas it uses are low-level components.

The following code follows the "program to an interface, not an implementation" principle, because you're calling `Bake` and `Deliver` on an abstraction. But it does *not* follow the DI principle, because your first block of code still depends on some concrete `Pizza` types.

```
public class PizzaStore
{
    public void OrderPizza(PizzaType type)
    {
        Pizza pizza;
        switch(type)
        {
            case PizzaType.FourSeasons:
                pizza = new FourSeasonsPizza();
            //...
        }

        //do something with pizza
        pizza.Bake();
        pizza.Deliver();
    }
}
```

By using the factory method pattern, or the abstract factory pattern, you're following *both* principles. Now you're programming against an abstraction *and* you're depending solely on abstractions. The pizza store depends on two abstractions: `Pizza` and `PizzaFactory`.

```
public class PizzaStore
{
    private PizzaFactory factory;

    public PizzaStore(PizzaFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void OrderPizza(PizzaType type)
    {
        Pizza pizza = factory.CreatePizza(type);

        //do something with pizza
        pizza.Bake();
        pizza.Deliver();
    }
}
```

So yes, the DI principle includes the "program to an interface" principle.

Comment: Well, exactly this book led to this question as it introduces these two separate principles as something different but the explanation is not sufficient for me. At best I can see `program to an interface` to be already included in `depend on abstractions` which I see as just saying of `strive for loose coupling` in different words.

Comment: @LeNoob I've updated my post, hope it's clearer now. I do agree with you in that the DI principle includes *programming to an interface*.

Answer (score -2):

In GoF Patterns book you can find definition of "interface". ***The set of all signatures defined by an object's operations is called the interface to the object.*** Interfaces in this book was declared in .h files and separated from implementation. So, given principles are synonymous.

.NET developers not familiar with GoF Patterns book can be confused by [.NET interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx).